# Cannot access page on this server (python and selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access a product page from this site, but it shows that I cannot access it on this server, I added an user agent and used a vpn but those didn't work... Any help is appreciated

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

def get_product(driver: Chrome, id: int):
    driver.get(MAIN_URL.format(id))

    link = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-clicktype="product_tile_click"]')[0].get_attribute('href')
    driver.get(link) # Cannot access this link

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    # ...

MAIN_URL = 'https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm={}&refinement=1'


options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

driver = Chrome(options=options)

products = []
product_ids = [333346]
for product_id in product_ids:
    products.append(get_product(driver, product_id))

print(products[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple things you can try: like trying with a browser then a different browser, using a proxy or TOR, add a delay like time.sleep() in case you are trying to access the page too quickly ?